# Use d3.js on a new window

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html-table, console, window

Is it possible to use d3.js when opening new windows? For example, I am trying:

```
new_window = window.open("userpage.html");
new_window.document.write("<html><body>");
new_window.document.write("<table id=\"usertable\">");
new_window.document.write("</table>");
new_window.document.write("</body></html>");    
table = d3.select("#usertable");
console.log(table);
var thead = table.append("thead");
var tbody = table.append("tbody");
var columns = ["dataset"];

thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .text(function(column) { console.log(column); return column; });
```

It doesn't work and the ouput of the first console.log is

```
[
Array[1]
0: null
length: 1
parentNode: HTMLHtmlElement
__proto__: Array[0]
]
```

I think `0: null` is not good.

Comment: How does it not work? You might have to add the closing table tag before trying to select it in d3.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: ok, I've edited the question, still not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

- I think you're opening the new window incorrectly - generally, you either open a URL with content, or you use `""` as the URL and write your content into a blank window. Opening a URL like `"usertable.html"` and then writing `<html><body>` doesn't make sense. Finally, even with a blank window, you don't need to write `<html><body>` - the browser will generally provide these nodes by default.
- Using `d3.select` is going to look, by default, in the current document. In order to access the body of the newly opened window, you'll need to pass in `new_window.document` - in fact, you'll need to pass in `new_window.document.body`, since you can't append anything to `document` without a `HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERROR`.
- I also don't think it's a good idea to mix D3 with `document.write` as you're doing here. D3 selects nodes in the DOM, and the way you have the code now, I don't think your `table` is actually a well-formed node until after you've tried to select it. D3 is perfectly good at inserting new DOM nodes - use it instead.

Putting all this together yields something like this:

```
var newWindow = window.open('');

var newWindowRoot = d3.select(newWindow.document.body);

// now do some writing with D3
var data = [
    { foo: "Foo 1", bar: "Bar 1" },
    { foo: "Foo 2", bar: "Bar 2" }
];

var table = newWindowRoot.append('table');

var rows = table.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data);

rows.enter().append('tr');

var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
    .data(function(d) { return d3.entries(d); });

cells.enter().append('td');

cells.text(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/gQf7J/