# Running D3 in node.js, what am I missing?

Tags: node.js, d3.js, coffeescript

Selecting an item with `d3.select('#chart')` doesn't work, even if I create the globals window and document.

Selecting it manually with `document.querySelector('#chart')` seems to work somehow.

```
jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom
document = jsdom('<html><head></head><body><div id="chart"></div></body></html>')
window = document.parentWindow

d3 = require('d3')
data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]

x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([0, 420])

//works
chartDiv = document.querySelector('#chart')
d3.select(chartDiv).selectAll("div").data(data).enter().append("div").style("width",(d) -> x(d) + "px").text((d) -> d)

//doesn't work
d3.select('#chart').selectAll("div").data(data).enter().append("div").style("width",(d) -> x(d) + "px").text((d) -> d)
```

Is there something missing? :\

Comment: What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: I don't get one, the `<div id="chart">` just remains empty.

Comment: Is `<div id="chart">` in the DOM when you go looking for it?

Comment: yes, when I use document.querySelector('#chart') works, but d3.select('#chart') doesn't.

Comment: Do you by any chance have in the DOM more than a single div with `id="chart"`? (Not that this would totally explain the discrepancy, but it is a weird error to begin with).

Comment: No, this is all I did. I got jsdom and d3 over npm, ported the d3 example to coffeescript and it didn't work. Then I tried to load a node directly from `document` and injected it to d3 and it worked. I looked into the d3 source and at one point it saved the global `document` and `window` object, so I moved the require of d3 down after those objects are created...

Comment: Did moving the require solve your problem?

Comment: The moved require was already in the (not working) example I postet in the question

Comment: d3 captures its own reference to `document`, as seen on line 11 in the [source code](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/d3.js). As I understand it (haven't tried JSDOM before) this is a problem, since this captured reference doesn't point to your jsdom-created `document`. Did you see [this thread](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/1044)? TLDR but seems to be discussing your issue. I would also expect that making `document` a global, like `global.document = jsdom('...')` could be a workaround, but that thread doesn't claim so.

Comment: ah I see, yes probably the bug that came back in 3.3.x :D okay, thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems logical that `d3.select('#chart')` does not work in your case, because the div you're aiming at is not on the current page.

You're loading some html as a string with jsdom, and try to replace the `window` variable to point at this new page.

But changing the window variable in your scope doesn't affect the d3 internal selectors. That's why you achieve to select your div with `document.querySelector('#chart')` and not directly `d3.select('#chart')`

As referenced in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369823/use-d3-js-on-a-a-new-window), you can make a selection on body, and then use subselections:

```
{jsdom} = require('jsdom')
d3 = require('d3')

# make a d3 selection on the new page body
document = d3.select(jsdom("""<html>
    <body>
      <div id="chart"></div>
    </body>
  </html>""").body)

data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]

x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([0, 420])

# make a subselection within the body
d3.select('#chart')
  .selectAll("div")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("width",(d) -> x(d) + "px")
  .text((d) -> d))
```